# Как разобрать JSON в DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, парсер, pandas, dataframe

На такой запрос по URL:

```
https://space.com/fat-menu/full...
```

Получаю такой JSON в ответ:

```
data: {
2416: {},
3361: {
id: 3361,
title: "Смартфоны, ТВ и электроника",
parent_id: 0,
manual_url: "",
border: 0,
logos: [],
icon_src: null,
category_id: 4627949,
top_category_id: 4627949,
target_blank: 0,
banner_mobile_src: "",
on_subdomain: 0,
is_portal: false,
banner_href: "",
banner_src: "",
children: {},
popular_categories: [],
outer_link: false
},
4306: {},
```

Следующим этапом, я разбираю этот JSON и из нужных мне значений формирую DataFrame.

При попытке отображения возникает данная ошибка:

> ```
> raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
> KeyError: "None of [Index(['title', 'parent_id'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
> ```

Вот мой код:

```
import json
import itertools
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
from urllib.parse import urlsplit


url = ""


r = requests.get(url)


df = pd.json_normalize(r.json().get("data"))

#print(df.columns.tolist())
print(df[['title','parent_id','category_id','manual_url']])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cols = ['title','parent_id','category_id','manual_url']

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json().get("data")

df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(d)[cols] for d in data.values()], ignore_index=True)
```

---

результат:

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
                             title  parent_id category_id                                         manual_url
0            Ноутбуки и компьютеры          0       80253  https://rozetka.com.ua/computers-notebooks/c80...
1      Смартфоны, ТВ и электроника          0     4627949  https://rozetka.com.ua/telefony-tv-i-ehlektron...
2                  Бытовая техника          0       80025                         https://bt.rozetka.com.ua/
3                  Товары для дома          0     2394287  https://rozetka.com.ua/tovary-dlya-doma/c2394287/
4         Инструменты и автотовары          0     4627858  https://rozetka.com.ua/instrumenty-i-avtotovar...
5              Сантехника и ремонт          0     4628418  https://rozetka.com.ua/santekhnika-i-remont/c4...
6               Дача, сад и огород          0     2394297  https://rozetka.com.ua/dacha-sad-ogorod/c2394297/
7                Спорт и увлечения          0     4627893  https://rozetka.com.ua/sport-i-uvlecheniya/c46...
8        Одежда, обувь и украшения          0     1162030     https://rozetka.com.ua/shoes_clothes/c1162030/
9               Красота и здоровье          0     4629305  https://rozetka.com.ua/krasota-i-zdorovje/c462...
10                  Детские товары          0       88468                https://rozetka.com.ua/kids/c88468/
11              Канцтовары и книги          0     4625734  https://rozetka.com.ua/office-school-books/c46...
12  Алкогольные напитки и продукты          0     4626923  https://rozetka.com.ua/alkoholnie-napitki-i-pr...
13              Товары для бизнеса          0     4627851  https://rozetka.com.ua/tovary-dlya-biznesa/c46...
14                Услуги и сервисы          0     4630262  https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi-i-servisi/c4630262/
15        Продовольственные наборы          0     4660608  https://rozetka.com.ua/prodovolstvennie-nabori...
16          Лето ждет! Сейл до 50%          0        None          https://rozetka.com.ua/promo/summerswait/
```